Comparing every latitude and longitude in a dataframe
Probably in over my head here as I'm still learning R...
I have a dataframe containing a column with longitude values and another column with corresponding latitude values.  I want to find long/lat locations that are within a defined distance from any other long/lat location in the dataframe - e.g., all locations that are within, say, .005 distance (both longitudinally and latitudinally) from any other location.
I hope that's a clear description.  Thanks in advance for any help.
I haven't really tried anything as I'm unsure of how to proceed in R.

Welcome to SO! Which part specifically are you running into trouble with? If it's the geometry, I'd suggest looking into the sf package, which has a function st_distance so you don't have to worry about non-euclidean geometry (unless you're just wanting to know if a point within a quadrangle centered on another point?). If it's the comparing every location, the outer function might be your friend. Let us know and I can elaborate on either part.

Thank you for your reply!  My uncertainty is how to compare every location.  I'll check out the outer function.  I've got a lot to learn in R still.

This probably isn't exactly what you're looking for, but hopefully it will help point you in the right direction:
# some example data
df <- data.frame(
  lon = c(-114.0719, -114.0723, -114.0754, -114.0801, -114.0755),
  lat = c(  51.0447,   51.0404,   51.0505,   51.0303,   51.0400)
)
# define the maximum distance
MAX_DIST <- 0.005

# calculate a matrix of distances between points
dist_mat <- dist(
    df,
    method = "maximum"
  ) |>
  as.matrix()
# set the diagonals to inifinity, so they won't be counted
diag(dist_mat) <- Inf

# for each point, check if the distance to any other point is
#   less than the threshhold
is_nearby <- apply(dist_mat < MAX_DIST, 1, any)

# filter the data frame by which points have nearby neighbors
df_filtered <- df[is_nearby,]

I interpreted your question as looking to select all points that are within both 0.005 degrees longitude and 0.005 degrees latitude of any other point - for this we can use dist with method = "maximum". If you're instead looking for the actual distance, check out the package sf. You'd need to convert df to vector geometry using st_point, then use st_distance in place of dist.
If the purpose of any of these functions is unclear, you can type ? followed by the function name in RStudio to get the documentation, for example, ?apply for help on apply().

Yes!  Works great (once I figured out that a blank row in my dataframe was messing things up).  Thank you very much.

If I can ask a follow-up question?  How can I run the same series but with a dataframe that has other columns (e.g., street address corresponding to the longitude and latitude)?  In other words, how can I create the matrix using only 2 specific columns in the dataframe?

@TwentyandChange Using base R, change the first argument of data from df to df[c("lon", "lat")] (or whatever your lat-long columns are called). Enter ?"[.data.frame" in the R Studio console for more info on subsetting data frames. Alternatively, use the package dplyr: select(df, c(lon, lat)). Happy to be able to help!
